# Center child within a parent that has no height or width

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a popover system, and I have two divs, the `popover-container` and the `popover`. The container is a `0px` by `0px` div that takes care of the positioning relative to the page. I would like the `popover` child to be centered so that the parent is in the middle.

```
<div class="popover-overlay">
  <div class="popover-container" style="left: 40px;top: 40px;">
    <div class="popover shadow_card-light"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.popover-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 500;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.popover-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}

.popover {
  min-height: 20px;
  min-width: 50px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 10px;
}
```

So currently the origin looks like this (the circle is the container, the rectangle is the actual popover the user would see)

[image]

What I would want is the origin to be like this:

[image]

I've tried putting flex centering, margin centering and nothing works.

Comment: Your code does not represent the image you have indexed with the question. Would you mind posting a working example with your issue on jsfiddle or codepen, please? Do you want the popover to pop over on hover? Will it be hanging inside the container?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? Your question was a bit unclear, but here is something.

The child is centered horizontally using the trick for absolute horizontal centering, which is:

```
.element{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

http://codepen.io/diego-fortes/pen/woGeBE